# Laravel でモデルの ER 図を生成するツールでデファクトはありますか?

Tags: laravel

Rails のプロジェクトでは、ジョインしたタイミングで [Rails ERD](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) のツールを用いて、 model たちの属性や関係性を可視化し、プロジェクト全体の理解をまず俯瞰する、ということをよくやります。

Laravel において、似たような、モデルたちの ER 図を出力するようなツールであって、 rails のように、デファクトでよく使われるものなどあったりしますか?

Rails と似たような機能を提供しているのが Laravel であるため、原理的には rails-erd 相当の機能は実現できそうな気がしますが、 Laravel エコシステムの肌感が分からず、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator

有名所だとこういうライブラリはありますが，「誰もが使うデファクト」という感じではないです．

参考までに，私はローカルで立てた DB に対して migrate して tbls(https://github.com/k1LoW/tbls) で ER 図を作ることが多いです